# Starter in Reactjs hooks Need to call an on click event openModal() from column.js components where event defined in Table.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Starter in React-hook project
I need to call `openModal()` from `column.js` which is defined in `Table.js` and need to fetch data and open the new modal form `Table.js`. Its react-hook project

**column.js**

```
// ** React Imports
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

// ** Custom Components
import Avatar from '@components/avatar'

// ** Store & Actions
import { getUser, deleteUser } from '../store/action'
import { store } from '@store/storeConfig/store'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'


// ** Third Party Components
import { Badge, UncontrolledDropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap'
import { Slack, User, Settings, Database, Edit2, MoreVertical, FileText, Trash2, Archive } from 'react-feather'

// ** Renders Client Columns
const renderClient = row => {
  const stateNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6),
    states = ['light-success', 'light-danger', 'light-warning', 'light-info', 'light-primary', 'light-secondary'],
    color = states[stateNum]

  if (row.user_avatar.length) {
    const server_base_url = "http://localhost:3001/uploads/"
    return <Avatar className='mr-1' img={`${server_base_url}${row.user_avatar}`} width='32' height='32' />
  } else {
    return <Avatar color={color || 'primary'} className='mr-1' content={row.user_fullname || 'John Doe'} initials />
  }
}

  
const renderSerialNo = row => {
  const param = useSelector(state => state.users.params)
  const serial = ((param.page - 1) * param.perPage) + row + 1
  return (serial)
  }

 
// ** Renders Role Columns
const renderRole = row => {
  const roleObj = {
    subscriber: {
      class: 'text-primary',
      icon: User
    },
    maintainer: {
      class: 'text-success',
      icon: Database
    },
    editor: {
      class: 'text-info',
      icon: Edit2
    },
    author: {
      class: 'text-warning',
      icon: Settings
    },
    admin: {
      class: 'text-danger',
      icon: Slack
    }
  }

  const Icon = roleObj[row.type_name] ? roleObj[row.type_name].icon : Edit2

  return (
    <span className='text-truncate text-capitalize align-middle'>
      <Icon size={18} className={`${roleObj[row.type_name] ? roleObj[row.type_name].class : ''} mr-50`} />
      {row.type_name}
    </span>
  )
}

const statusObj = {
  2: 'light-warning',
  0: 'light-success',
  1: 'light-secondary'
}

export const columns = (openModal) => [
  {
    name: '#',
    maxWidth: '3px',
    selector: 'serial',
    sortable: true,
    cell: (row, index) => (renderSerialNo(index))
  },
  {
    name: 'User',
    minWidth: '300px',
    selector: 'fullName',
    sortable: true,
    cell: row => (
      <div className='d-flex justify-content-left align-items-center'>
        {renderClient(row)}
        <div className='d-flex flex-column'>
          <Link
            to={`/apps/user/view/${row.id}`}
            className='user-name text-truncate mb-0'
            onClick={() => store.dispatch(getUser(row.user_id))}
          >
            <span className='font-weight-bold'>{row.user_fullname}</span>
          </Link>
          <small className='text-truncate text-muted mb-0'>@{row.user_name}</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  },
  {
    name: 'Email',
    minWidth: '220px',
    selector: 'email',
    sortable: true,
    cell: row => row.user_email
  },
  {
    name: 'Role',
    minWidth: '172px',
    selector: 'role',
    sortable: true,
    cell: row => renderRole(row)
  },
 {
    name: 'Status',
    minWidth: '138px',
    selector: 'status',
    sortable: true,
    cell: row => (
      <Badge className='text-capitalize' color={statusObj[row.user_status]} pill>
        {row.user_status_text}
      </Badge>
    )
  },
  {
    name: 'Actions',
    minWidth: '10px',
    cell: row => (
      <UncontrolledDropdown>
        <DropdownToggle tag='div' className='btn btn-sm'>
          <MoreVertical size={14} className='cursor-pointer' />
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu right>
          <DropdownItem
            tag={Link}
            to={`/apps/user/view/${row.user_id}`}
            className='w-100'
            onClick={() => store.dispatch(getUser(row.user_id))}
          >
            <FileText size={14} className='mr-50' />
            <span className='align-middle'>Details</span>
          </DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem
            tag={Link}
            to={`/apps/user/edit/${row.user_id}`}
            className='w-100'
            onClick={() => store.dispatch(getUser(row.user_id))}
          >
            <Archive size={14} className='mr-50' />
            <span className='align-middle'>Edit</span>
          </DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem className='w-100' onClick={() => openModal(row)}>
            <Trash2 size={14} className='mr-50' />
            <span className='align-middle'>Delete</span>
          </DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </UncontrolledDropdown>
    )
  }
]
```

**Table.js**

```
// ** React Imports
import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

// ** Invoice List Sidebar
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'

// ** Columns
import { columns } from './columns'
// ** Store & Actions
import { getAllData, getData } from '../store/action'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

// ** Third Party Components
import Select from 'react-select'
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate'
import { ChevronDown } from 'react-feather'
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component'
import { selectThemeColors } from '@utils'
import { Card, CardHeader, CardTitle, CardBody, Input, Row, Col, Label, CustomInput, Button } from 'reactstrap'

// ** Styles
import '@styles/react/libs/react-select/_react-select.scss'
import '@styles/react/libs/tables/react-dataTable-component.scss'

// ** Table Header
const CustomHeader = ({ toggleSidebar, handlePerPage, rowsPerPage, handleFilter, searchTerm }) => {
  return (
    <div className='invoice-list-table-header w-100 mr-1 ml-50 mt-2 mb-75'>
      <Row>
        <Col xl='6' className='d-flex align-items-center p-0'>
          <div className='d-flex align-items-center w-100'>
            <Label for='rows-per-page'>Show</Label>
            <CustomInput
              className='form-control mx-50'
              type='select'
              id='rows-per-page'
              value={rowsPerPage}
              onChange={handlePerPage}
              style={{
                width: '5rem',
                padding: '0 0.8rem',
                backgroundPosition: 'calc(100% - 3px) 11px, calc(100% - 20px) 13px, 100% 0'
              }}
            >
              <option value='10'>10</option>
              <option value='25'>25</option>
              <option value='50'>50</option>
            </CustomInput>
            <Label for='rows-per-page'>Entries</Label>
          </div>
        </Col>
        <Col
          xl='6'
          className='d-flex align-items-sm-center justify-content-lg-end justify-content-start flex-lg-nowrap flex-wrap flex-sm-row flex-column pr-lg-1 p-0 mt-lg-0 mt-1'
        >
          <div className='d-flex align-items-center mb-sm-0 mb-1 mr-1'>
            <Label className='mb-0' for='search-invoice'>
              Search:
            </Label>
            <Input
              id='search-invoice'
              className='ml-50 w-100'
              type='text'
              value={searchTerm}
              onChange={e => handleFilter(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <Button.Ripple color='primary' onClick={toggleSidebar}>
            Add New User
          </Button.Ripple>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}

const UsersList = () => {
  // ** Store Vars
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const store = useSelector(state => state.users)

  // ** States
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(10)
  const [sidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(false)
  const [currentRole, setCurrentRole] = useState({ value: '', label: 'Select Role' })
  const [currentPlan, setCurrentPlan] = useState({ value: '', label: 'Select Plan' })
  const [currentStatus, setCurrentStatus] = useState({ value: '', label: 'Select Status', number: 0 })

  // ** Function to toggle sidebar
  const toggleSidebar = () => setSidebarOpen(!sidebarOpen)

  // ** Get data on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllData())
    dispatch(
      getData({
        page: currentPage,
        perPage: rowsPerPage,
        role: currentRole.value,
        currentPlan: currentPlan.value,
        status: currentStatus.value,
        q: searchTerm
      })
    )
  }, [dispatch, store.data.length])

  // ** User filter options
  const roleOptions = useSelector(state => state.users.roleOptions)
 
  const statusOptions = [
    { value: '', label: 'Select Status', number: 0 },
    { value: '2', label: 'Pending', number: 1 },
    { value: '0', label: 'Active', number: 2 },
    { value: '1', label: 'Inactive', number: 3 }
  ]

  // ** Function in get data on page change
  const handlePagination = page => {
    dispatch(
      getData({
        page: page.selected + 1,
        perPage: rowsPerPage,
        role: currentRole.value,
        currentPlan: currentPlan.value,
        status: currentStatus.value,
        q: searchTerm
      })
    )
    setCurrentPage(page.selected + 1)
  }

  // ** Function in get data on rows per page
  const handlePerPage = e => {
    const value = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value)
    dispatch(
      getData({
        page: currentPage,
        perPage: value,
        role: currentRole.value,
        currentPlan: currentPlan.value,
        status: currentStatus.value,
        q: searchTerm
      })
    )
    setRowsPerPage(value)
  }

  // ** Function in get data on search query change
  const handleFilter = val => {
    setSearchTerm(val)
    dispatch(
      getData({
        page: currentPage,
        perPage: rowsPerPage,
        role: currentRole.value,
        currentPlan: currentPlan.value,
        status: currentStatus.value,
        q: val
      })
    )
  }

  // ** Custom Pagination
  const CustomPagination = () => {
    const count = Number(Math.ceil(store.total / rowsPerPage))

    return (
      <ReactPaginate
        previousLabel={''}
        nextLabel={''}
        pageCount={count || 1}
        activeClassName='active'
        forcePage={currentPage !== 0 ? currentPage - 1 : 0}
        onPageChange={page => handlePagination(page)}
        pageClassName={'page-item'}
        nextLinkClassName={'page-link'}
        nextClassName={'page-item next'}
        previousClassName={'page-item prev'}
        previousLinkClassName={'page-link'}
        pageLinkClassName={'page-link'}
        containerClassName={'pagination react-paginate justify-content-end my-2 pr-1'}
      />
    )
  }

  // ** Table data to render
  const dataToRender = () => {
    const filters = {
      role: currentRole.value,
      currentPlan: currentPlan.value,
      status: currentStatus.value,
      q: searchTerm
    }

    const isFiltered = Object.keys(filters).some(function (k) {
      return filters[k].length > 0
    })
    if (store.data.length > 0) {
      return store.data
    } else if (store.data.length === 0 && isFiltered) {
      return []
    } else {
      return store.allData.slice(0, rowsPerPage)
    }
  }


 // ** Opening modal
  const openModal= (row) => {
   //Here i need to get the value 
console.log(openModal)
    }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Card>
        <CardHeader>
          <CardTitle tag='h4'>User Lists</CardTitle>
        </CardHeader>
        <CardBody>
          <Row>
            <Col md='4'>
              <Select
                isClearable={false}
                theme={selectThemeColors}
                className='react-select'
                classNamePrefix='select'
                options={roleOptions}
                value={currentRole}
                onChange={data => {
                  setCurrentRole(data)
                  dispatch(
                    getData({
                      page: currentPage,
                      perPage: rowsPerPage,
                      role: data.value,
                      currentPlan: currentPlan.value,
                      status: currentStatus.value,
                      q: searchTerm
                    })
                  )
                }}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col md='4'>
              <Select
                theme={selectThemeColors}
                isClearable={false}
                className='react-select'
                classNamePrefix='select'
                options={statusOptions}
                value={currentStatus}
                onChange={data => {
                  setCurrentStatus(data)
                  dispatch(
                    getData({
                      page: currentPage,
                      perPage: rowsPerPage,
                      role: currentRole.value,
                      currentPlan: currentPlan.value,
                      status: data.value,
                      q: searchTerm
                    })
                  )
                }}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>

      <Card>
        <DataTable
          noHeader
          pagination
          subHeader
          responsive
          paginationServer
          columns={columns(openModal)}
          sortIcon={<ChevronDown />}
          className='react-dataTable'
          paginationComponent={CustomPagination}
          data={dataToRender()}
          subHeaderComponent={
            <CustomHeader
              toggleSidebar={toggleSidebar}
              handlePerPage={handlePerPage}
              rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
              searchTerm={searchTerm}
              handleFilter={handleFilter}
            />
          }
        />
      </Card>

      <Sidebar open={sidebarOpen} toggleSidebar={toggleSidebar} />
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default UsersList
```

I'm trying to implement this in react-hook project. Need to get resolved to open the modal and data need to be showed in `modal.Tried` everything and need to call `useState()` for define modal but in `column.js` its showing its violation of hooks components also its just need to export the column so need to get the `openModal()` event trgger in `Table.js`

Comment: make columns a function returning array like - `(openModal) => []` and in Table.js pass column prop as `<Table columns={columns(openModal)} {...otherProps} />`

Comment: can you please explain briefly with editing my  code sample.Since i cant pass columns and function from columns.js

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look like this:

````
**column.js**
// ** React Imports
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

// ** Custom Components
import Avatar from '@components/avatar'

// ** Store & Actions
import { getUser, deleteUser } from '../store/action'
import { store } from '@store/storeConfig/store'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'


// ** Third Party Components
import { Badge, UncontrolledDropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap'
import { Slack, User, Settings, Database, Edit2, MoreVertical, FileText, Trash2, Archive } from 'react-feather'



export const columns = (openModal) => [
  {
    name: '#',
    maxWidth: '3px',
    selector: 'serial',
    sortable: true,
    cell: (row, index) => (renderSerialNo(index))
  },
  {
    name: 'User',
    minWidth: '138px',
    selector: 'user',
    sortable: true,
    cell: row => (
      <Badge className='text-capitalize' color={statusObj[row.user_status]} pill>
        {row.user_status_text}
      </Badge>
    )
  },
  {
    name: 'Actions',
    minWidth: '10px',
    cell: row => (
      <UncontrolledDropdown>
       <DropdownItem className='w-100' onClick={() => openModal(row)}>
            <Trash2 size={14} className='mr-50' />
            <span className='align-middle'>Delete</span>
          </DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </UncontrolledDropdown>
    )
  }
]```


**Table.js**

```// ** React Imports
import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

// ** Columns
import { columns } from './columns'
// ** Store & Actions
import { getAllData, getData } from '../store/action'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

// ** Third Party Components
import Select from 'react-select'
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate'
import { ChevronDown } from 'react-feather'
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component'
import { selectThemeColors } from '@utils'
import { Card, CardHeader, CardTitle, CardBody, Input, Row, Col, Label, CustomInput, Button } from 'reactstrap'

// ** Styles
import '@styles/react/libs/react-select/_react-select.scss'
import '@styles/react/libs/tables/react-dataTable-component.scss'



const UsersList = () => {
  // ** Store Vars
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const store = useSelector(state => state.users)


  // ** Get data on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllData())
    dispatch(
      getData()
    )
  }, [dispatch, store.data.length])

  // ** User filter options
  const roleOptions = useSelector(state => state.users.roleOptions)
 
  const openModal= e => {
    //need to get the value here
    console.log(e)
  }
  
...

  return (
    <Fragment>
       <Card>
        <DataTable
          responsive
          paginationServer
          columns={columns(openModal)}
          sortIcon={<ChevronDown />}
          className='react-dataTable'
          paginationComponent={CustomPagination}
          data={dataToRender()}
         }
        />
      </Card>

      <Sidebar open={sidebarOpen} toggleSidebar={toggleSidebar} />
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default UsersList
````

Comment: Its showing ReferenceError: openModal is not defined error in columns.js:80

Comment: It should not throw error as openModal method is there in argument. Can you post exact code after update

Comment: Code is updated as per your request. Please look into it and give a solution